# Sharing to ONENOTE copies to Personal not ONEDRIVE Notebook

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, onedrive, onenote

Using a Nokia phone using Win 8.
When I 'share' a webpage to ONENOTE, it used to load it into the ONEDRIVE Notebook on the phone. Now all shares are being added to a ONENOTE notebook identified as PERSONAL. The PERSONAL folder doesn't SYNC to phone's ONEDRIVE.
1. I cannot transfer the notes from personal to onedrive. Is there a workaround?
2. Can I reset ONENOTE so that new 'shares' go to the ONEDRIVE syncable notebook?
Thanks for any feedback.